# Completing command name itself in zsh

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

I have a bunch of ZSH functions which are pretty verbose, and I'd like to use zsh completion on them. Example:

```
qq-enum-dns-txfr-host
qq-enum-dns-brute-rev
qq-enum-dns-tcpdump
qq-enum-web-php-lfi-logfile
qq-enum-smb-tcpdump
qq-enum-web-php-ffuf-common-php
qq-enum-ftp-tcpdump
```

When I type `qq-tcp`<kbd>Tab</kbd> I'd like to get completions of:

```
qq-enum-dns-tcpdump
qq-enum-smb-tcpdump
qq-enum-ftp-tcpdump
```

All the documentation I can find deals with how to complete arguments to a given command or function, but doesn't say how to use the substring (not prefix) completion to figure out which function to use in the first place.

I guess I could refactor so that each function is instead an argument to a `qq` command. But is there a simpler way I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [configure the completion system extensively](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Completion-System-Configuration) with the [`zstyle`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#index-zstyle) builtin. By default, completion only tries to add a suffix, but you can change this with a [`matcher-list`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-matcher_002dlist_002c-completion-style) style. To apply the style to all completions:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list …
```

To apply the style only when the context is a [command](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_002dcommand_002d_002c-completion-context), and only for commands that are functions:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:*:-command-:*:functions matcher-list …
```

What goes after `matcher-list` is a list of [completion matching control specifications](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-Widgets.html#Completion-Matching-Control). Zsh tries them in order, and stops as soon as one finds a match. Use the empty specification to just add a suffix; you'll usually want this first except in very specific contexts where this makes it hard to reach some completions. You can use an `r` specification to allow partial completion to the left of punctuation characters: `r:|[-+./_]=*` means that wherever the string to complete contains one of the characters `-+./_`, a matching completion can have anything (anything matching `*`, which matches everything) to the left of this punctuation character. For example, `qq-tcp`<kbd>Tab</kbd> completes to anything matching `qq*-tcp*` (the final `*` is from regular suffix completion).

```
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list '' 'r:|[-+./_]=*'
```

You can activate this through the interactive basic customization interface `compinstall`, under “Matching control”, as “partial-word completion”.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for, thanks! I have further questions, but I'll put those in a new question.

Answer (score 0):

In your `~/.zshrc`, you can declare aliases which will be taken in account for the completion

```
alias qq-tcpdump-enum-dns='qq-enum-dns-tcpdump'
alias qq-tcpdump-enum-smb='qq-enum-smb-tcpdump'
alias qq-tcpdump-enum-ftp='qq-enum-ftp-tcpdump'
```

(Then you can `source ~/.zshrc` in already open terminals to get the aliases available.)